# ical file sync to iOS devices protect using htacess

Tags: php, ios, lamp, icalendar

I have an ical file generated on a server. I would like it to be sync with ios devices. It works fine if left open, but as soon as I add something like an htaccess file it breaks.

Is it possible to have an ical file sync with iphone and provide some sort of authentication behind the scenes to keep the ics file protected. I am in a LAMP environment.

Thanks,
Bart

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seemingly have [PHP](http://php.net) with its trivial [basic authentication setup](http://php.net/manual/en/features.http-auth.php). Note this isn't particularly secure, but it will do the job:

```
<?php
if (!isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'])) {
    header('WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="My Realm"');
    header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');
    echo 'Text to send if user hits Cancel button';
    exit;
} else {
  # lookup $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'] and the hash of {$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']} on the backend.
  # return the contents of your ical file
}
```

I hope that helps, if not, leave a comment indicating what needs clarification and I'll add  the relevant code.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I know this is not great protection but I wanted something so it is not in the open. 

I was able to get this to work. IOS brought up a dialog box when it went to "sync" for the first time at least and appears to remember the password(?). I am in iOS 6.1

However just so I follow. I have not seen ($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']) since I would call the file directly the ics file. Would this need to point to a php file that would run first then generate the ics file and headers. 

Sorry returns are not working for me comments...

Comment: No, put that as your service endpoint and have the iCal file in a separate directory accessible to the web user and it will work.

Comment: Sorry I am missing this still.  

I put the iCal file in a web accessible folder with no protection? Where does the php file live and how does it prevent people from accessing the iCal file.